# Active Directory Problems

Tags: active-directory

This morning, something wierd happened with our Active Directory.

We have a website that authenticates users against our Active Directory. It has worked flawlessly for weeks. The code involving this has never changed. When I launch a copy of the website on my local computer within the IDE (VS2008), it authenticates users correctly, and determines what groups they belong to correctly. When I navigate to the actual website though, it authenticates but fails to retrieve any group information. While I am open to the possibility that it would be code, I am very skeptical of this since the code has not changed since the last time it was working, which was yesterday.

I wrote a quick app using the same exact programming code, but in a compiled WinForm instead of a webpage. The App can authenticate and retrieve all the groups flawlessly. So it is just the website that, all of the sudden, cannot access the groups. I am sure this is relevant, but I am not sure how =)

Being a programmer and not a Server Admin, I am unsure where to begin in hunting down this problem and will appreciate any assistance the community at large can provide.

Answer (score 1):

If you have anonymous browsing turned off, check to see that the account the web app is running under has the correct permission.

Comment: HI Joe. Thank, Unfortunately, that was one of the first things I checked. Anonymous browsing is still enabled on the website.